# When I run /usr/bin/time my_program, how to kill my_program?

Tags: shell

I want to check how long time my program takes. Then I using "/usr/bin/time my_program". When it takes more than 5 seconds, I want to kill it. I tried "kill -9 TIME_S_PID", time is killed, but my_program is still running. So how to kill my_program?

Thanks.

Comment: Should be a question for superuser.com, with the "unix" and "kill" tags.

Comment: Try `killall my_program`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `killall`, as its name suggests, will kill all instances of your program. A better way would be to make a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$$" # print the PID of the current process
exec my_program
```

Then you execute `/usr/bin/time my_wrapper_script`, which prints PID of this instance of your program, and kill it when you want with `kill -9 "$my_prog_pid"`.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this using 2 scripts below:

the first I name it **mytime**

```
#!/bin/bash
##############################################################################################################
# This script is used to perform a /usr/bin/time over a command and deliver the kill signal to the good exe
# Usage : mytime command args
# The result will be in a file name /tmp/command.PID.txt where pid is the current pid
# example:
#  ./mytime sleep 10000 &
#  kill pid of mytime
#  cat /tmp/sleep.*.txt
##############################################################################################################
# store the current pid
P=$$
CMD=$1
signalisation ()
{
# deliver the signal to good pid ie the son of /usr/bin/time
  S=$1
#    echo Signal $S >>/tmp/trace_$P.txt 
  PF=$(cat /tmp/pid$P.txt)
  rm /tmp/pid$P.txt
#    echo pid du fils de time : $PF >>/tmp/trace_$P.txt 
  kill $S $PF
}
trap "signalisation 1" 1 
trap "signalisation 2" 2 
trap "signalisation 3" 3 
trap "signalisation 15" 15 
/usr/bin/time -f '%e %M # Elapsed real time (in seconds) and Memory Max' -o /tmp/$CMD.$P.txt storepid /tmp/pid$P.txt $* &
wait %1
exit $?
```

and this one used by the previous I named it **storepid**

```
#!/bin/bash
###########################################################################################
# this script store the pid in the file specified by the first argument
# the it executes the command defined by the others arguments
# example:
# storepid /tmp/mypid.txt sleep 100
# result sleep 100 secondes , but you can kill it before using kill $(cat /tmp/mypid.txt)
###########################################################################################
WHERE=$1
shift
echo $$ >$WHERE
exec $*
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Soulseekah said, killall my_program works.